# MySql Error for finding entry distance given coordinates

Tags: mysql, location

I have a SQL statement for finding distances from items in a table. mySQL sucks at giving errors and I can not find my mistake inside my statement below. I think I just need a second pair of eyes at this point:

```
SELECT idL
     , idS
     , N
     , lat
     , lng
     , t
     , bn
     , bb
     , bi
     , dt ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('33.11') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-117.28') ) + sin( radians('33.11') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
  FROM table1
     , table2 
 WHERE idL = idS 
HAVING distance < '10' 
 ORDER 
    BY distance asc
```

I have tried messing around with the quotes taking out adding them in etc. I can not get this query to execute at all.

Comment: So tell us about the dt function

Comment: it takes the lat and long coordinates typed in, and looks at all the entries in the database and only returns the ones within a distance of ten miles. I have used it successfully before, but this is the first time I am joining two tables with it.

Comment: Assuming that dt is a real function within your database then I think there's no syntax error here.

Comment: Alternatively, if dt is not a function, then you're missing a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed a comma after your dt field :

```
SELECT idL
     , idS
     , N
     , lat
     , lng
     , t
     , bn
     , bb
     , bi
     , dt
     , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('33.11') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-117.28') ) + sin( radians('33.11') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
  FROM table1
     , table2 
 WHERE idL = idS 
HAVING distance < '10' 
 ORDER 
    BY distance asc
```